# Replace every occurrence of pattern in a string by an incremental pattern

Tags: bash, perl, sed, increment

I have many input files like this one:

```
(((A:1,B:2)100:4,C:5)87:4,D:3);
```

I want to replace `100` and `87` by `#1` and `#2`. So the idea is that everytime the pattern `)*:` is matched the `*` is replaced by an incremental string: `#1`,`#2`...

The only thing I've figured out up to now is this perl one-liner: `perl -ple 's/\)*\:/\)$n++\:/g' file` but it gives the following output:

`(((A)++:1,B)++:2)100)++:4,C)++:5)87)++:4,D)++:3);`

and I can't see where I'm wrong.

Any `bash` or `perl` (or other!) script would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You need the `e` modifier in perl to make it evaluate the arithmetic in the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close: you need to evaluate the replacement text as a perl expression:

```
perl -pe 's/\).*?:/ ")#" . ++$n . ":" /ge' file
```

```
(((A:1,B:2)#1:4,C:5)#2:4,D:3);
```

Or, with look-arounds

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\)).*?(?=:)/ "#" . ++$n /ge' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ while( sub(/)[0-9]+/,")#"++i) ); }1' file
(((A:1,B:2)#1:4,C:5)#2:4,D:3);
```

Apparently nawk requires the open brace in the RE to be escaped:

```
$ awk '{ while( sub(/\)[0-9]+/,")#"++i) ); }1' file
```

Comment: When I try it it says: `$: command not found`   (I am a Mac user)

And by the way, would it work if I have more than 10 values to substitute? Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Ok! Here is the error message that I get now:

`awk: illegal primary in regular expression )[0-9]+ at [0-9]+

 source line number 1

 context is
 
{ while( >>>  sub(/)[0-9]+/,")#"++i) <<< `

Comment: You can imagine that if I ask you this question it is because I had a look but did not manage to fix it ;-) however this awk one-liner is of great interest for me so if you do know how to fix it I would greatly appreciate :)